# Получаю 504 Gateway Time-out при настройки прокси на мой ip, в чем ошибка?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, docker, proxy, развертывание

Задача чтобы сайт открывался по домену а не ip адресу.
Выбрал путь проксирования запросов через Nginx Proxy Manager.
Приложение локально запущено в контейнере через докер на 8000 порту. Я в корне создал папку с конфигом прокси, далее создал там файл docker-compose.yml в котором прописан стандартный конфиг, но я изменил порт локальной прослушки на 8945. Файл Выглядит вот так:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '8945:81'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
```

Дальше я запускаю контейнер, где все успешно

**Настройки докера:**

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: python:3.10
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/blog
    container_name: blog-web
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file: .env
    working_dir: /opt/blog
    command: /bin/bash -c "scripts/run-server.sh"
```

**run-server.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

VENV=./.venv

# if not exists VENV -> create VENV
if [ ! -d $VENV ]; then
  `which python3` -m venv $VENV
  $VENV/bin/pip intsall -U pip
fi
`which python3` -m venv $VENV

# Upgrade pip
$VENV/bin/pip install -U pip
# Installing requirements from file
$VENV/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt

# Do migrate (for creating tables in the database)
$VENV/bin/python manage.py migrate
$VENV/bin/python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

# Run django
echo "Run Django"
$VENV/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Следующим шагом я захожу в панель администратора в Nginx Proxy Manager и вот мои настройки там:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итого просто получаю 504 Gateway Time-out по домену. В чем я ошибся и как это можно решить?

Comment: Вам в [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: почему именно туда?

Comment: Этот форум больше подойдёт под вашу тематику, т.к. там обычно и делают какие технические детали, можете ещё попробовать [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), в Server Fault конкретно обсуждают сервера. Правда там всё на английском.

Comment: Ээээ, ну http://raisfoto.ru:8000/ открывается. Там мужик с лимоном и бутылкой. А чё ты хотел, если твой вебгуй (зачем он тебе?) походу перекрывает настройки докеркомпоза?

Comment: Что за вебгуй? Я немного не понял..  Сейчас обновлю вопрос и дополю его настройками докера если ты про это.

Comment: `webgui` - Так понятнее?

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю как это относится к моей проблеме ? На каком пункте я допустил ошибку ? Пока не понимаю где капать..

Comment: Ты указал в вебгуе 8000-й порт? Указал. Он открывается? Открывается. Сайт? Сайт. Хочешь, чтобы на 80-м открывался? Ну так а чё указал не 80-й?

Comment: Вы правы, я почему-то не думал о том, что можно локальный порт сделать 80.. Спасибо!